# How to ensure a certain order of method calls with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python

I'm working on a package with classes like these:

```
# pseudo-code
class Block:
    def start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_default # fail-safe

class BlockPersistent(Block):
    def start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_saved_state # does nothing if no state was saved
        super().start()

class BlockRemote(Block):
    def start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_remote_server # does nothing if network I/O fails
        super().start()
```

An application may use any of those three classes as bases for own classes. But when the application code wants to define a block that supports both client/server communication and persistent state, it must pay attention to the correct order:

```
class SomeBlock(BlockRemote, BlockPersistent):
    ...
```

because the only intialization order that makes sense in this case is:

1. try to get the most recent value from the server first
2. then try if we have some saved value
3. use the default value as last resort

---

I'd like to achieve that:

```
class SomeBlock(BlockPersistent, BlockRemote): # wrong order!
```

will call all the `start` functions in the correct order too (or at least fail with a clear error message about wrong order). Is there any recommended approach for my problem?

---

I hope I'll get some helpful feedback. If not I will probably implement something like this:

```
class Block:
    def _init_subclass(cls, ...)
        super()._init_subclass(...)
        # recursively visit all cls.__bases__,
        # collect all _start methods,
        # sort by PRIORITY (from highest to lowest)
        cls.starts = [...]

    def start(self):
        for func in self.starts:
            func(self)

    PRIORITY = 0
    def _start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_default # fail-safe

class BlockPersistent(Block):
    PRIORITY = 10
    def _start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_saved_state # does nothing if no state was saved

class BlockRemote(Block):
    PRIORITY = 20
    def _start(self):
        if not initialized:
            initialze_from_remote_server # does nothing if network I/O fails
```

Comment: Essential reading: [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).